# VSCode Extension: "a dynamic import callback was not specified"

Tags: vscode-extensions, es6-modules, vscode-debugger

In my VSCode extension js file, I am using an import() statement to import an .mjs file in a command definition. This works well in my local debugging environment.

However, when I package the extension using 'vsce package' and install it in a vscode app elsewhere, I see 'a dynamic import callback was not specified' error when import() call is made from the code.

My development & testing vscode versions are same 1.74.2. How can I fix the error? Is there some option in building the 'vsce package' that solves this?

Comment: Are you developing with typescript?

Comment: When you are packaging your extension using vsce package, all the files are bundled, and it can cause the dynamic imports to fail due to reasons like incorrect paths or bundling issues. try to path.join(__dirname, './myModule.mjs') to compute the absolute path

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70620025/11107541

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right you can debug using `.mjs` file.
But you can't deploy it.
As vscode is an electron app it will not support `.mjs`.
An alternative you can do is use babel where you can transpile the code before running `vsce package`