# Missing object initializations in transpiled pdfjs-dist module

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, webpack, babeljs, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a vscode extension that requires extracting text from a provided PDF.
The extension works fine during development but after exporting to .vsix I run into issues.
On digging deeper I found that since [vscode is an electron app it will not support .mjs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75832761/10997981) which pdfjs-dist uses.

Following that answer, I started transpiling pdfjs-dist using babel-loader.

On testing the transpiled module, I run into the issue of some objects not being initialized.

Example

In `/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.mjs` we have

```js
const GlobalWorkerOptions = Object.create(null);
GlobalWorkerOptions.workerPort = null;
GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = "";
```

in transpiled `pdfjs.bundle.js`
I don't see this initialization

this causes issues when I try to use the module [pdfjs.bundle.js](https://s3.filebin.net/filebin/0ce1731d3651cbad1ee5f0a1550886e27b7e9470c7c5c1692da9d4c6c28b2cdc/4cc5682d57cd3bce4c1b3c1eaaab869f045308e26999d388479c7fcc2ee5c9d8?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=7pMj6hGeoKewqmMQILjm%2F20231127%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231127T064042Z&X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-cache-control=max-age%3D60&response-content-disposition=filename%3D%22pdfjs.bundle.js%22&response-content-type=text%2Fplain%3B%20charset%3Dutf-8&X-Amz-Signature=67a3e17a70bd9c1c01f1a80f2a845de32ee4a53924856984abc6cbdaec0896cb)

```js
const pdfjsLib = await import('../dist/pdfjs.bundle.js');

pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.mjs";

const pdfData = new Uint8Array(fs.readFileSync(pdfPath));

const pdfDocument = await pdfjsLib.getDocument({ data: pdfData }).promise;
```

I get

```
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'workerSrc')
```

and on commenting out `pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.mjs";`

```
TypeError: pdfjsLib.getDocument is not a function
```

#### Wrapper script `./src/pdfjsWrapper.js`

```js
import 'pdfjs-dist';

export default pdfjs-dist;
```

#### webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  target: 'node', // for VS Code extensions
  entry: {
    pdfjs:'./src/pdfjsWrapper.js' 
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: {
      name: 'pdfjsLib',
      type: 'umd', // Universal Module Definition
    },
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'

  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        
        exclude: (modulePath) => {
            // Exclude 'vscode' module
            if (modulePath.includes('node_modules/vscode')) {
              return true;
            }
  
            // Exclude 'fs' module
            if (modulePath.includes('node_modules/fs')) {
              return true;
            }
  
            // Exclude 'weaviate-ts-client' module
            if (modulePath.includes('node_modules/weaviate-ts-client')) {
              return true;
            }
  
            // Include all other modules
            return false;
          },
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
            compact: false // to have optimised code
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

#### .babelrc

```json
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Comment: is `getDocument` a function exported from the bundle file

Comment: does it work if you add the missing init code in the bundle file

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by downgrading pdfjs-dist to 3.11.174